# Why does georeferencing reduce the image resolution?

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing

I'm trying to use a raster as a base image in my QGIS project.  It is a building schematic which is fairly high resolution.  Importing this into QGIS, it seems that the only way to re-position an image is through georeferencing.  If I do this, the resolution of the image drops significantly, to the point of now being usable for any presentation setting.

I'm trying to do one of two things, and I don't care which:

1. Reposition and rotate a raster layer; or
2. Georeference a raster layer without sacrificing image quality.

Comment: When you georeference the image is it stretching it significantly? I can see the image becoming grainy if it needs to be resized in order for it to match up with other layers. In this case your image may not be as high resolution as it needs to be.

Comment: How are you outputting the image where you see the poor resolution - saving the map from print composer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are georeferencing the image you can choose an output pixel size.  It sounds like your image is being resampled when you georeference it.  What you may want to do is to choose the same, or better pixel size (ie: 0.1 meters) and choose Cubic Convolution as the resampling method.